# Most concise way to assign value from hash only if it exists?

Tags: perl

I find myself often writing code like this:

```
if ($optionalParamsRef->{verbosity}) {
    $settingsHash{verbosity} = $optionalParamsRef->{verbosity};
}
```

However, it seems very verbose to repeat `$optionalParamsRef->{verbosity}` twice.  Is there a shorter way?

**Edit**: Yes, I realize this is checking for true/false and not 'exists'.  What I'm looking for is a concise functional equivalent to this.

Comment: Note that this is not testing "if it exists". It will fail for "falsy" values.

Comment: This technique will add the key 'verbosity' (w/ value undef) to $optionalParamsRef if it didn't already exist. No big deal if you don't care about altering $optionalParamsRef.

Answer (score 4):

Note you are checking `$optionalParamsRef->{verbosity}` for **true**, not **exist**.

Possible way to do this:

```
foreach my $k (qw/verbosity param1 param2 param3/) { #Enumerate keys here
     $settingsHash{$k} = $optionalParamsRef->{$k} if exists($optionalParamsRef->{$k});
}
```

Comment: `%settingsHash = (%settingsHash, %$optionalParamsRef);`

Comment: Thanks.  Based on the two answers here so far, both solutions involve assigning it to a new variable with a shorter name.  I guess I was hoping there was a more 'native' way to avoid repetition.

Comment: @melpomene its good way if he wants to merge `optionalParamsRef` into `settingsHash`. Sometimes its better, sometimes not.

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned, your code checks for false-ness. If you considered false values as non-existant, you could have used the logical or. Probably this is not what you want.

```
$settingsHash{verbosity} = $optionalParamsRef->{verbosity} || $default;
```

But maybe defined-ness is enough. It's still no check for existence, but if your hash doesn't contain `undef` values, this could be enough:

```
$settingsHash{verbosity} = $optionalParamsRef->{verbosity} // $default;
```

using the "new" defined-or operator `//` instead of the logical or `||`. I know these examples are not equivalent to the code you posted because they alwas assign something, but in my experience, this is often useful, so maybe it could help.

Comment: the // was what I was looking for when I hunted down this question, but isn't exactly what OP asked for.  gave me a bit of a quandary, I was forced to up vote both this and the other answer that answered exactly what was asked to be fair to both those that give exact answers and those that give useful alternatives :)  thank you either way lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $v = $optionalParamsRef->{verbosity};
$settingsHash{verbosity} = $v if $v;
```

```
for ($optionalParamsRef->{verbosity}) {
    $settingsHash{verbosity} = $_ if $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise functional equivalent:

```
sub {$_[0]=$_[1] if $_[1]}->($settingsHash{verbosity}, $optionalParamsRef->{verbosity});
```

However, IMO, the main problem with your code is that you are only conditionally setting $settingsHash{verbosity}, keeping you from doing something simpler like:

```
$settingsHash{verbosity} = $optionalParamsRef->{verbosity} || somedefault
```

or even:

```
%settingsHash = ( %defaultSettings, %$optionalParamsRef );
```